# Conditional check to see if a bootstrap.css is included in a theme

Tags: plugin-development

I am creating a shortcode plugin for Bootstrap framework that will go along with my theme. However since this would be released to the plugin, if a users's theme already has Bootstrap.css included, is there a way for me to check this from a plugin?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You *might* be able to use [`wp_style_is()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_style_is) to do this:

```
$style = 'bootstrap';
if( ( ! wp_style_is( $style, 'queue' ) ) && ( ! wp_style_is( $style, 'done' ) ) ) {
    //queue up your bootstrap
    wp_enqueue_style( $style, $path_to_bootstrap, $deps, $ver, $media );
}
```

This comes with all the same caveats as @Milo's solution -- it'll only work *if* the copy of bootstrap.css was registered or enqueued with a handle of `bootstrap`.

#### References

- [`wp_style_is()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_style_is)
- [`wp_enqueue_style()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_style)

Comment: Thanks Pat. This does the job. As @Milo suggested will have to show some warning/notice too. But this is great.

Answer (score 7):

There's no bulletproof way of doing this, as a theme developer could add the `bootstrap.css` file directly to a theme file, or enqueue it under any number of handles, or rename the css file to something else.

You could check the `$wp_styles` global for `bootstrap` in a handle or filename, but this may fail (as noted above) or give you a false positive if `bootstrap` happens to be in a handle or file unrelated to *your* bootstrap. It's also possible to build custom versions of bootstrap, so even if you did locate it, it may not contain all of the styles it's assumed to contain.

Here's a quick example of peeking into the enqueued styles:

```
function wpa_inspect_styles(){
    global $wp_styles;
    var_dump( $wp_styles );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpa_inspect_styles', 9999 );
```

Probably the best option, in my opinion, is to do some cursory checking and inform the user that you *may have* detected bootstrap in their theme, enqueue the file by default, and provide an option to disable the stylesheet.

Comment: Thanks Mila. Showing a user a message as you suggested seems to be a great way to be sure.